# what exactly is python typing.Callable?

Tags: python, typing

I have seen `typing.Callable`, but I didn't find any useful docs about it. What exactly is `typing.Callable`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable

Comment: Something that you can call as a function.  So `Callable[[int, list[int]], bool]` would be a function that takes two arguments, an int and a list of integers, and returns a boolean.  Python 3.10 adds the ability to do more complicated things with `Callable`, but most users won't need that.

Comment: @Chris. The docs only work well if you already know what a callable is.

Comment: @FrankYellin. And [PEP 677](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0677/) removes the need to use `Callable` explicitly at all. Your example could be written as `(int, list[int]) -> bool`

Comment: FYI: PEP 677 as linked above was **rejected**, so that syntax doesn't work.
(but happened 7 days after the above comment was written)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) is the type you use to indicate a [callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable). Most python types that support the `()` operator are of the type [`collections.abc.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Callable). Examples include functions, [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod)s, [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)s, bound methods and lambdas.

In summary, anything with a `__call__` method (which is how `()` is implemented), is a callable.

[PEP 677](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0677/) attempted to introduce implicit tuple-with-arrow syntax, so that something like `Callable[[int, str], list[float]]` could be expressed much more intuitively as `(int, str) -> list[float]`. The PEP was rejected because the benefits of the new syntax were not deemed sufficient given the added maintenance burden and possible room for confusion.

Comment: Oh that's great, I hadn't seen PEP 677!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. I just found it totally by accident because of this question. I've never really used typing much to begin with, and it won't come out until Python 3.11

Comment: Note: PEP 677 has been rejected. Could you please update your answer?

Comment: @decorator-factory. Updated. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 23):

The [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module is used for type hints:

> This module provides runtime support for type hints.

#### What are type hints?

The documentation provides this example:

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello ' + name
```

> In the function `greeting`, the argument name is expected to be of type `str` and the return type `str`. Subtypes are accepted as arguments.

#### How to use `typing.Callable`

Assume you want to define a function that takes two integers and performs some kind of operation on them that returns another integer:

```
def apply_func(a: int, b: int, func) -> int:
    return func(a, b)
```

So the expected type of the `func` argument in `apply_func` is "something that can be called (e.g. a function) that takes two integer arguments and returns an integer":

```
typing.Callable[[int, int], int]
```

#### Why bother with type hints in the first place?

Using type hints enables you to perform type checking. If you use an IDE like PyCharm or Visual Studio Code, you'll get visual feedback if you're using unexpected types:

[image: Unexpected type callout in PyCharm]

Answer (score 10):

I would like to add to other answers that starting with Python 3.9, `typing.Callable` is deprecated. You should use `collections.abc.Callable` instead.

For more details and the rationale, you can take a look at [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/)

Comment: I don't understand why Callable is moved to `collections.abc` though. It is a valid way to type functions which has nothing to do with collections at all!

Comment: It appears that `collections.Callabable` also works in Python 3.9.

Comment: @PaulWintz It's deprecated though, and in 3.10 it's removed

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable).

Short version, `Callable` is a type hint that indicates a function *or* other object which can be called.

Consider a simple example below. The `bar` parameter is a callable object that takes two ints as parameters and returns an int.

```
>>> def foo(bar: Callable[[int, int], int], a: int, b: int) -> int:
...     return bar(a, b)
...
>>> foo(int.__add__, 4, 5)
9
>>> class A:
...     def __call__(self, a, b):
...         return a * b
...
>>> foo(A(), 6, 7)
42
>>> foo(lambda x, y: x - y, 8, 3)
5
>>>
```